# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax err or access violation: 1064(PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1{main}thrown in modifiercours.php online9)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm making an update function and am using the mvc pattern and am getting this error only while trying to execute this funtion the database connection has been effectued succesfully the create function works fine
this is the code in modifiercours.php

```
 <?php 
 include_once '../config.php';
   require '../Model/CoursM.php';


  $db=config::getConnexion();
  $sql="SELECT * FROM 'cours' where Idc=?";
  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute([$_GET['Idc']]);
  $prod=$query->fetchall();
  ?>
```

this is the code in my controllers CoursC.php file

```
    function Modifieev($cours)
   {
  $sql= "UPDATE `Cours` SET  
 titre=:titre,matiere=:matiere,datep=:datep,Idc=:Idc,auteur=:auteur WHERE Idc=Idc  ";
 $db=config::getConnexion();
 try{ $recipesStatement = $db->prepare($sql);
 $recipesStatement->execute([ 
                'titre'=>$cours->gettitre_Cours(),
                'matiere' =>$cours->getmatiere(),
                'datep'=>$cours->getdatep(),
                'Idc'=>$cours->getIdc(),
                'auteur'=>$cours->getauteur(),
                   
                       //'id'=>$cours->getId_Cours(),

             ]);
```

}
'''
and this is modifier.php

```
      <?php 
  include_once '../config.php';

  include_once '../Controller/coursC.php';
  include_once '../Model/coursM.php';
              
  if(!isset($_POST['titre'])||!isset($_POST['matiere'])||!isset($_POST['datep'])||
  !isset($_POST['Idc'])||!isset($_POST['auteur']))
 {
echo "erreur de ";
 }



  $cate=new cours($_POST['titre'],$_POST['matiere'],$_POST['datep'],$_POST['Idc'],$_POST['auteur']);

  $cat=new coursC();
  $cat->Modifieev($cate);

  header('location:http://localhost/web/View/affichercours.php');

  ?>
```

Comment: Idc=Idc  should be Idc=:Idc with the placeholder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: I tried changing it like you said and nothing happened